# Android time picker auto change hours when minutes get scrolled

Tags: android, android-timepicker

When I'm scrolling minutes on TimePicker for example I have "08:00" after I scroll minutes to "59", hours automatically get scrolled to "7" so new time will be "07:59". 
The same way if I have "07:59" and I scroll minutes to "00" hours automatically will get scrolled to "8" so time will be "08:00"

This logic works for Nexus 7(2), HTC One but now working for all Samsung devices.
Is there a bug or should I add this logic manually for them?

Thank you!

Comment: Working too on Samsung or not working? I guess that the system is responsible for that.

Comment: It seems there is a typo, its not working on Samsung devices.

Comment: varies from the hardware and software encode in devices of different complanies.Totally depends on firmware

Comment: Are you using the picker dialog or have you created the picker manually using number picker?

Comment: I'm using android.widget.TimePicker