# How to prevent the wheel spinner TimePicker in a .NET MAUI Android application auto-increment to the next hour when the minutes go past 59?

Tags: c#, android, maui

I am trying to prevent the hour spinner to auto-increment when the minutes wheel goes past the 59-minute mark.

[Android Wheel Picker (16:59)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKP5Z.png)

After scrolling to the 00, the hour part auto-increments and I want to prevent this.

[Android Wheel Picker (17:00)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhi7z.png)

P.S. The hour wheel also auto-decrement when you roll the weel back to 59 minutes.

Since, the wheel spinner is a legacy Android TimePicker I had to create a new TimePickerHandler (inherited from TimePickerHandler) and register it in MauiProgram.cs.

This is the code for the handler:

```
public class LegacyTimePickerHandler : TimePickerHandler
{
    protected override TimePickerDialog CreateTimePickerDialog(int hour, int minute)
    {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new(
            Context,
            Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Dark ? global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloDialogNoActionBarMinWidth : global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLightDialogNoActionBarMinWidth,
            (s, e) =>
            {
                VirtualView.Time = new TimeOnly(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute, 0).ToTimeSpan();
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(VirtualView.Time);
                PlatformView.Text = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
            },
            VirtualView.Time.Hours,
            VirtualView.Time.Minutes,
            true);

        return timePickerDialog;
    }
}
```

And I registered in MauiProgram.cs as follows:

```
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(TimePicker), typeof(Platforms.Android.Handlers.LegacyTimePickerHandler));
#endif
                });
```

I guess I'm trying to find the event that is fired when the wheel value changes (minutes, in order to prevent the hour wheel from auto-incrementing) or something similar.

Comment: i suggest you bind The time property of timepicket to a depency property. Now in the setter method of this dependency property you check if the new value.seconds is 59 or 0 and if that is the case change the new value.hour the old value.hour YOu could also achive this by overwriting the time.setter function in your class

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, this cannot work, since the the binding only fires when you accept the changes (when you press the 'Accept' button). Not when you scroll the spinners.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. The solution is based on this Stack Overflow post: [TimePickerDialog disable hours change when scrolling minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801375/timepickerdialog-disable-hours-change-when-scrolling-minutes)

The changes needed are to create a custom TimePickerDialog that inherits from TimePickerDialog and to create a new instance of this custom TimePickerDialog in the TimePickerHandler as shown below. The full code is:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using TimePicker = Android.Widget.TimePicker;

namespace Timesheets.Platforms.Android.Handlers
{
    public class LegacyTimePickerHandler : TimePickerHandler
    {
        protected override TimePickerDialog CreateTimePickerDialog(int hour, int minute)
        {
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new CustomTimePickerDialog(
                Context,
                Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Dark ? global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloDialogNoActionBarMinWidth : global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLightDialogNoActionBarMinWidth,
                (s, e) =>
                {
                    VirtualView.Time = new TimeOnly(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute, 0).ToTimeSpan();
                    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(VirtualView.Time);
                    PlatformView.Text = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
                },
                VirtualView.Time.Hours,
                VirtualView.Time.Minutes,
                true);

            return timePickerDialog;
        }
    }

    public class CustomTimePickerDialog : TimePickerDialog
    {
        private TimePicker mTimePicker;

        public CustomTimePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, EventHandler<TimeSetEventArgs> callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, bool is24HourView) : base(context, theme, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView)
        {
        }

        public override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();

            Class classForid = Class.ForName("com.android.internal.R$id");
            Java.Lang.Reflect.Field timePickerField = classForid.GetField("timePicker");
            mTimePicker = (TimePicker)FindViewById(timePickerField.GetInt(null));
            Java.Lang.Reflect.Field minuteField = classForid.GetField("minute");

            NumberPicker minuteSpinner = (NumberPicker)mTimePicker.FindViewById(minuteField.GetInt(null));
            minuteSpinner.SetOnValueChangedListener(null);
        }
    }
}
```